# How to show images from assets or internal storage in a gallery to pick from?

Tags: android, android-intent, gallery, android-gallery, internal-storage

I am currently looking for a way to let the user pick an image from my apps data. The images are currently in the Assets folder, but may be shoved to the internal storage if that's easier.

I don't want all the files to be stored in a public storage.

I am using the following code to pick from the users gallery and it works well. I hope to somehow use a similar code for the current situation.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

1. Is there a way to change that code to show the images from the apps assets folder or it's internal storage, instead of the users public gallery-files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a "Gallery" myself by using a [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html).

I used the code from that side to create an ImageAdapter, with a few changes:

```
 public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList <String> data = new ArrayList();

    // I'm using a yamlReader to fill in the data, but it could instead just be hardcoded.
    fillDataWithImageNames();

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        // The images are in /app/assets/images/thumbnails/example.jpeg
        imageView.setImageDrawable(loadThumb("images/thumbnails/" + data.get(position) + ".jpeg"));
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Drawable loadThumb(String path) {
    try {
        // get input stream
        InputStream ims = mContext.getAssets().open(path);
        // load image as Drawable
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
        // set image to ImageView
        return d;
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try that and be sure that you have any file explorer app installed on your device.

```
Uri selectedUri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/yourFolder/");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(selectedUri, "resource/folder");

if (intent.resolveActivityInfo(getPackageManager(), 0) != null)
    {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
else 
    {
      // if you reach this place, it means there is no any file 
      // explorer app installed on your device
    }
```